# How to download, rename and save images generated by user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jszip

I'm building an web app where the user will input the **old filename** and **new filename** and he will be able to download the files generated.

I'm new to coding and specially Javascript, so I decided to ask for you guys to have a look and maybe help me to find a solution.

[image]

I tried using Jszip but can't figure out how to configure it to get user's input instead of predefined urls.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.0.2/jszip-utils.min.js"></script>   
<script>
var urls = [
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-1.jpg", 
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-2.jpg",
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-3.jpg",
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-4.jpg",
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-5.jpg",
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-6.jpg",
                 "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/AMSPP-BL-7.jpg"];
var nombre = $scope.meetingName;
//The function is called
compressed_img(urls,nombre);

function compressed_img(urls,nombre) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  var count = 0;
  var name = nombre+".zip";
  urls.forEach(function(url){
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
         throw err; 
      }
       var filename = url.replace(/.*\//g, "");
       zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true, createFolders: true });
       count++;
       if (count == urls.length) {
         zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
            saveAs(content, name);
         });
       }
      });
  });
}
</script>    
<br/>
<br/>
<center>
Click the button to generate a ZIP file
<br/>
<input id="button" type="button" onclick="compressed_img(urls,nombre)" value="Create Zip"></input>
</center>    
</body>    
</html>
```

I expect to download and rename files specified by the user instead of predefined urls as my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compressed_img(urls,nombre) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  var count = 0;
  var name = `${nombre}.zip`;
  var givenName = `test`;
  var counter = 1;
  urls.forEach(function(url){
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {

      console.log(data)
      if(err) {
         throw err; 
      }
       var extention = url.split('.').pop();
       zip.file(`${givenName}${counter}.${extention}`, data, { binary: true, createFolders: true });
       count++;
       counter++;
       if (count == urls.length) {
         zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
            saveAs(content, name);
         });
       }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Alright, that looks promising(even I don't really understand much)...do u mind telling me where this code should go ? and how to connect it to the old name & new name input box ? Sorry if asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.0.2/jszip-utils.min.js"></script>   
<script>


function compressed_img() {
  let name = document.getElementById('nm').value;
  let num = document.getElementById('num').value;
  let ext = document.getElementById('ext').value;
  var urls = new Array();

  for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    urls.push(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://img.tenniswarehouse-europe.com/new_big/${name}-${i}.${ext}`)
  }
  if(!name){
      alert("please provide the name first.")
      return false;
  }

  var zip = new JSZip();
  var count = 0;
  var nameZip = `${name}.zip`;
  var givenName = name;
  var counter = 1;
  urls.forEach(function(url){
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {

      console.log(data)
      if(err) {
         throw err; 
      }
       var extention = url.split('.').pop();
       zip.file(`${givenName}${counter}.${extention}`, data, { binary: true, createFolders: true });
       count++;
       counter++;
       if (count == urls.length) {
         zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
            saveAs(content, name);
         });
       }
      });
  });
}
</script>    
<br/>
<br/>
<center>
Click the button to generate a ZIP file
<br/>
Name To be Downloaded : <input type="text" id='nm' placeholder="AMSPP-BL">
Number Of Files : <input type="number" id='num' placeholder="7">
Files extension : <input type="text" id='ext' placeholder="jpg">

<input id="button" type="button" onclick="compressed_img()" value="Create Zip"></input>
</center>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Hey ! looks like you didn't actually understood my question :( you still use predefined urls...your input doesn't work :( it still download the images that you have specified under `var urls` instead of building the urls from the input something like : main url is always : www.example.com/images/ + input code 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg 6.jpg, 7.jpg Hope that make sense now. You are very close ! Also would be nice to be able to have multimple inputs, not just a single one, if that make sense also ? Thank you !

Comment: as you describe, i think my new answer will satisfies you. Now you have to provide the file-name, number of URL to be generated, and the file extension.
OR if you can enter the array of files name LIKE : ['AMSPP-BL-1.jpg','AMSPP-BL-2.jpg','AMSPP-BL-3.jpg','AMSPP-BL-4.jpg'], it can also be a solution, if want this type then ping me. thanks....

Comment: You actual code meets 50 % of my expectation ! First, we don't need that file format field, the files are always going to be .jpg. Second - number of pictures like I wrote in the main answer will vary from 1 to 7, so please check all 7 files on the web for a good 200 response and download all available images. Third, small issue with your code, it downloads the images but the order isn't correct. For example picture number 1 on the website becomes number 2 when download, do you know why ?  And last but really important, we don't rename the files still :( Check my picture try to understand !